# I succeeded allocating a pointer to an array of 3 ints in the heap, but I still don't understand how does the access to the array work?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, new-operator

After several trials I've succeeded allocating a pointer to an array of 3 `int`s with a *new expression*. In the snippet below, I show first the use of this pointer in the stack, and then I show where I've got with the heap allocation, after several trials.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    // First, pointer p to an array of 3 int's in the stack.

    int a[3] = { 10, 11, 12 };
    int(*p)[3] = &a;
    std::cout << **p << "  " << *(*p + 1) << "  " << *(*p + 2) << '\n';
    std::cout << p[0][0] << "  " << p[0][1] << "  " << p[0][2] << '\n';

    // Second, the pointer is allocated on the heap.

    int(**q)[3] = new (int(*)[3]) {p};

    // That's what I've got after several trials. But I'm still trying to
    // understand how does the access to the array work in the next two lines of code?

    std::cout << ***q << "  " << ***q + 1 << "  " << ***q + 2 << '\n';
    std::cout << q[0][0][0] << "  " << q[0][0][1] << "  " << q[0][0][2] << '\n';
}
```

The code prints

```
10  11  12
10  11  12
10  11  12
10  11  12
```

See [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5fdfe88a17d9585)

**Edit** @A.S.H. found an error in my code, in his comment below. I'm making the necessary changes to clarify the example.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    // First, pointer p to an array of 3 int's in the stack.

    int a[3] = { 100, 200, 300 };
    int(*p)[3] = &a;
    std::cout << **p << "  " << *(*p + 1) << "  " << *(*p + 2) << '\n';  // Change here
    std::cout << p[0][0] << "  " << p[0][1] << "  " << p[0][2] << '\n';

    // Second, the pointer is allocated on the heap.

    int(**q)[3] = new (int(*)[3]) {p};
    std::cout << ***q << "  " << *(**q + 1) << "  " << *(**q + 2) << '\n';  // Change here
    std::cout << q[0][0][0] << "  " << q[0][0][1] << "  " << q[0][0][2] << '\n';
}
```

With these changes the code is much clearer. If I knew about this error before, I wouldn't have placed the question. Thanks @A.S.H. for your input.

Comment: Try `int a[3] = { 100, 200, 300 };` and check the result again ;)

Comment: A hint on how important this is: I have been programming professionally since 1980, and have never ever used `***q` or `q[0][0][2]`. Please spend your time learning something useful!

Comment: @A.S.H I understand what you mean. See my edit above.Thanks for your hint.

Comment: @François-MarieArouet you are welcome. For precision, this wasnt actually to show an error, but a hint to help you interpret what is going on. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`q` is a pointer to a pointer to an array. So if you dereference it twice, you get an array. If you dereference it one more time, it undergoes an array-to-pointer conversion to give a pointer to the first element of that array (`10`) and is then dereferenced, so you get `10`. Addition has lower precedence than the unary prefix operators, so `***q + 1` means `(***q) + 1`, so it's `11`.

`q[0][0][0]` is equivalent to dereferencing `q` 3 times, because `q[i]` just means `*(q+i)`. For `q[0][0][1]`, it's the same as dereferencing twice and then returning the element at index `1` of the array, so it's `11`.